# CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state; nothing seems to fix this?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I get this error when trying to run my app. "CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state."

This was never an error just minutes ago. How do I fix this? I've tried different suggestions, but none worked. I tried running 'sudo gem install cocoapods', but after I did it never seemed to finish installing. So I terminated the process, thinking maybe it just installed and didn't let me know it finished, and of course, I still get the same error. Any suggestions are appreciated, as I have no clue what to do next.

Comment: I fixed it. This is what I did: I had a dependency in my pubspec.yaml file, called "image picker". I deleted it, ran pub get, and then the error fixed itself. I also updated to the latest Android Studio, but I do not know if that helped or not. I hope the solution I found can help someone else.

Comment: Great! You can add it as an answer so more people can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. This is what I did: I had a dependency in my pubspec.yaml file, called "image picker". I deleted it, ran pub get, and then the error fixed itself. I also updated to the latest Android Studio, but I do not know if that helped or not. I hope the solution I found can help someone else.